# How declare cell object variable in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am looping a Range in excel as follows and need to get the position of the cell as well as getting intellisense for the object, tried  CL as Cell but it does not work

```
Sub Excel_Collection1()
    Dim rng As Range
    'Dim CL As Cell
    For Each CL In rng
        If CL.Value <> "" Then
            MsgBox (CL.Value)
        End If
        
    Next CL
```

So for each cell in the range I need to get its position C1, C2 in order then to create a dynamic range starting at its location to lets say A1:A20

Thanks for your help

Comment: `Dim CL as Range`. It is a `Range` with a single row/column... But iterating between the range cells is the slower iteration way. Try better describing of what you try accomplishing. We maybe can suggest faster ways of doing it...

Comment: There is no `Cell` object type - it's a `Range`

Comment: Fane, I have a sheet with multiple columns, starting always at C3 and might end at P or Q or R, so number of columns changes. So I named a range from C3 to Z3 and check if it the cell contains a value. if it containes a value I need to search, select and copy all underneat C3 that are not empty to another sheet, then go the following celle in the range and so on

Comment: Hello, I am aware, that there is no such thing like a Cell-Object. I simply don't get why?
To me, a Range is a (rectangular?) bunch of cells, which can be subdivided into rows, cols and cells.
Instead in Microsoft's logic, a Range is a bunch of Ranges and if i want to loop through its cells (or cols or rows) i have to loop through a set of ranges instead.
To me, this is totally counterintuitive.
Does anybody have a plausible explanation why it is as it is??

Answer (score 1):

As already written in the comments: There is no `Cell` object type. A cell is simply a Range that contains only one single cell, or with other words, a `Range` can contain one or more cells.

If you are unsure what type you need, declare a variable of type `Variant`, assign what you need to that variable and check what the variable contains using the debugger tools, eg, set a breakpoint at the `Debug.Print statement:

```
Sub testSub()
    Dim cell As Variant
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A5")
        Debug.Print "..."
    Next
End Sub
```

Now open the **Locals Window** (View->Locals Window) and you can see the data type:

[image]